# NSArray with multiple Objects

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a array with 10 objects , sometimes out of 10 objects ,some objects tends to `null` and  if any of the object is null ,Its comes as empty in my  `UIPickerView` but I want If the value of any object is null then it should be skipped.. what I am trying to do is

```
if([ob1 isEqualToString:@""]){
NSArray *Ar =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ob2,ob3,ob4,ob5,ob6,ob7,ob8,ob9,ob10,Nil];}
else if [ob2 isEqualToString:@""] {}
```

but this will be long chain if i skip any null value this way..what should be the better way.

Comment: you should first try filtering your array and remove the null values then use it for UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the 10 objects can be `nil` (note - use `nil` for Objective-C object references) then you need to do it the hard way:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (ob1) [array addObject:ob1];
if (ob2) [array addObject:ob2];
if (ob3) [array addObject:ob3];
// ...
if (ob10) [array addObject:ob10];
```

This checks if each object is `nil` or not. If you also want to make sure it is not `nil` and it has a non-zero length value, change each `if` condition to:

```
if (ob1.length) ...
```

Comment: for me if value of object isequaltostring @"" then it should be skipped

Comment: OK, then change all of the `if` statements to check the `length`. Please note that your question states that some of the objects are `nil`. That is VERY different from having a value of `@""`. If none are actually `nil`, then you would be better off to have the objects in an array instead of 10 separate variables. Then you can create a new array with just the non-empty (not non-nil) values using a simple loop.

Comment: @rmaddy  you are checking for each object is write.Don't you think so it will increase your file size unnecessary.Instead you can fill in an NSArray with one line then filtered out. Many lines of code may be omit.

Comment: @iPhoneDev In the question, the OP states that some of the objects might be `nil`. You can't put `nil` objects in an array. Plus, the original code has 10 separate variables. My answer was based on having 10 variables where some could be `nil`. If it turns out that none are actually `nil`, then using 10 variables is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSMutableArray`, instead of `NSArray`. Like as below:

```
NSMutableArray *m_array = [NSMutableArray array];

//Now you can check your objects if nil or empty string @"" and add it to the array.

if(object1==nil || [object1 isEqualToString:@""])
{
   //the string is empty do not add anything to array
}
else
{
  //we have a proper object
  [m_array addObject:object1];
}

//here you'll get the array will only proper objects.
//use this array to fill your pickerView data.
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is incorrect. If `object1` is `nil`, your code then tries to add `object1` to the array. That will crash.

Comment: That's better. But of course there is no need to check for `nil` in Objective-C. You can safely do `if (object.length == 0)`. This will be true if `object1` is `nil` or if it is the empty string.

Comment: object.length==0 returning true, is sort of a hack-type programming. It relies on the mercy of compiler that an object that does not exists returns a value 0. That's improper coding practice. But, yeah its one another way to achieve it.

Comment: I don't think it's a hack. It's a reliance on the Objective-C specification that `nil` objects can be sent messages and the result is always `0`.

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 rmaddy is correct.  See Apple's [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html) guide.  As described there: "If you expect a return value from a message sent to nil, the return value will be nil for object return types, 0 for numeric types, and NO for BOOL types. Returned structures have all members initialized to zero."

Comment: @rmaddy and Nate Chandler : In your own answer you've mentioned it already. That its compiler specific. Its shown as an Obj-C rule, but its actually a compiler's rule.

Comment: @rmaddy and Nate Chandler : And yes its a hack. Apple has provided it to us officially. Defintion of a hack : "A task achieved from a system by breaking the universal conceptual rule via a method is called a hack". Here, the universal concept is that "a property of an object cannot be accessed when it doesn't exists." Now, if Apple has made an arrangement of provide it as zero, its a hack! It elevates you from handling that exception in its own environment. Such techniques are not universal and should not be practiced according to me.

Answer (score 0):

First take an `NSMutableArray`.
And an `NSArray` which is initialize with all objects including null.
Then check if the object is not null then add on to the mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (![[objectArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) {
      [array addObject:[objectArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
  }
```

Where ObjectArray is NSArray contain all the objects.We can see it takes less amount of coding.

Comment: How will this work? The problem is that some of the objects are `nil` pointers. Therefore they can't be in `objectArray` to begin with.

Comment: If you use `initWithObjects:`, the array won't have any values past the 1st nil object. Try it. Use `initWithObjects:` and pass in 10 variables. Make sure some of the variables are `nil`. See what ends up in the array.

Comment: sorry my mistake as he is checking with empty string I assume that all are strings.you can see isEqualToString is used on main question.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this condition

```
if ((ob2 == [NSNull null]) && ob2 == nil) {

}
```

Comment: `ob2 = [NSNull null]` assigns `[NSNull null]` to `ob2`.

Comment: @NateChandler that was typing mistake and it doesn't assign anything because that is under condition.

Comment: @eptdeveloper Sorry but using `=` in an `if` statement *will* do the assignment and the value of the expression will be the value of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem regarding nil objects and wrote a category on `NS(Mutable)Array` for that. 
So instead of:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (ob0) [array addObject:ob0];
if (ob1) [array addObject:ob1];
if (ob2) [array addObject:ob2];
if (ob3) [array addObject:ob3];
```

You can use `arrayWithObjectsNil` for skipping nil objects:

```
id obs[] = { ob0, ob1, ob2, ob3 }; // Assuming obj1 and obj3 are nil. 
  NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithObjectsNil:obs size:sizeof(obs)]);
> ( 0, 2 )
```

Or use `arrayWithObjectsNull` for transforming nil objects to `[NSNull null]`:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithObjectsNull:obs size:sizeof(obs)]);
> ( 0, "<null>", 2, "<null>" )
```

With the category it is also possible to use mutability and write it this way:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObjectNil:ob0];   // skip, if ob0 is nil
[array addObjectNull:ob1];  // add [NSNull null], if ob1 is nil
...
```

There are also other methods with the same logic.

You'll find the category named [Nilus](https://github.com/beheim/Nilus) on GitHub.